# Ayuda con css y bordes

Tags: css

necesito una guia de como armar algo como lo siguente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado hacer un div y ponerle borde pero se me descuadra todo y no tengo muy claro como hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes te invito a que realices el [tour] para que comprendas el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Tambien revisa [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Que has intentado? Puedes editar la pregunta y agregar el código que tienes hasta ahora

Comment: puedes lograrlo usando las pseudo clases **:before** o **:after**

Answer (score 1):

Algo así [Ejemplo en codePen](https://codepen.io/dmsanchez86/pen/gqEjVp)

```css
*{
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    }

    div{
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  border: solid 10px blue;
  margin: 3rem 0 0 2rem;
  position: relative;
    }

    div:before{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -2rem;
  right: -2.5rem;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1; }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Deberías adjuntar el HTML también, para que vea la distribución, dado que pide una guía. La propiedad border debería ser red y el background blue. Y, por último, aunque está bien ayudar, no está bien hacerle los deberes a los demás. Debería agregar que código ha intentando, al menos, pues en las normas pone eso, que se agregue todo el código posible y se explique el problema. Solicitar una guía no es un problema, es una comodidad.

Comment: Solo hice un ejemplo muy básico y sencillo, ya que el saque sus conclusiones y aprenda